# Getting the first attribute value instead of the one I changed to (HTML)

Tags: javascript

I have some images on an html page.  When an image is clicked, I change the image src to show that it is selected.  This is working properly.  When another image on the same row is selected, I would like to unselect the other images on that row.  I've got code below.  Unfortunately, when i call getAttribute("src"), I am only getting the initial value that is set when the page is loaded and defined below.  I've tried this with both an input type of image as well as an img tag.  Any ideas?

```
var imgOther = document.getElementById(bwdTerms[i] + i);
var imgSrc = imgOther.getAttribute("src");
if (imgSrc.indexOf("_selected") > -1) {
     imgOther.click();
}
```

If I'm not explaining this right, and I doubt I am, I'm glad to answer questions.  I've also tried this with jquery.

TIA

Comment: Are you sure this whole block is running after their original `src` was modified?

Comment: @GerardoFurtado I thought of that, and I have double checked to make sure that I am checking the images before any other changes.

Comment: thanks @GerardoFurtado.  I just decided to do things a different way and it worked almost first shot.

Answer (score 2):

There's not enough code here for me to see where you're going wrong. I rewrote it to assign all images to one variable, then add onclick events to each one that reset all images before setting the clicked one to the new src.

```js
const images = document.querySelectorAll(".cats > img");
images.forEach(img => {
  img.addEventListener("click", function(e){
    images.forEach(img => img.src = img !== e.target ? img.dataset.image : e.target.src);
    e.target.src = e.target.src === img.dataset.image ? "https://placekitten.com/500/500" : img.dataset.image;
  });
});
```

```css
.cats{
  display: flex;
  gap: 20px;
}

.cats > img {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}

.cats > img:hover {
 cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="cats">
  <img src="https://placekitten.com/200/200" data-image="https://placekitten.com/200/200">
  <img src="https://placekitten.com/210/200" data-image="https://placekitten.com/210/200">
  <img src="https://placekitten.com/200/210" data-image="https://placekitten.com/200/210">
  <img src="https://placekitten.com/230/210" data-image="https://placekitten.com/230/210">
  <img src="https://placekitten.com/300/250" data-image="https://placekitten.com/300/250">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @symlink.  I decided to do things a different way, and it just worked for me.